# JQuery scroll event doesn't fire immediately after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a jQuery function to make a div stick to the top of the page, after it is scrolled below the original position. However, after a button click (postback), you have to scroll above the div first before it works again.

I think this may be the troublemaker:

```
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"
```

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function fixedNav() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 150) {
        $('#navigation').addClass('fixedNav');
        $('#mainContent').addClass('pushedMainContent');
    }
    else {
        $('#navigation').removeClass('fixedNav');
        $('#mainContent').removeClass('pushedMainContent');
    }
}
function isPostBack() {
    fixedNav();
}
$(window).scroll(function () {
    fixedNav();
})
})
```

I have been going over the function for an hour and I can't seem to find a fix. (I even added the same function to the isPostBack but that didn't help) Any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Fix: (thank you @charlietfl)

```
<script>see "My jQuery"</script>
<body onload="fixedNav()">
```

Comment: Try calling the function right away on page load

Comment: That seems to work! Thanks a lot, however I don't understand the difference between document.ready and onload

Comment: is it async postback?

Comment: it was a synchronic postback

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    fixedNav();
})
```

creates a function to be called when someone scrolls, but when the page reloads, nobody is scrolling. *And*, if I'm not mistaken, the page will load with the classes that are *in the markup*, not the classes that were last applied.

So you have to manually call `fixedNav()`, to reapply the new classes.

---

I don't think this is relevant to your question but google 'document.ready vs onload' for answers to the difference b/t ready and onload. (If you want to compare two things, always use `vs` when googling.

Here's an SO answer: 
[ready vs onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Actually understanding what goes wrong is always better than just a fix. Thanks